# How to visualize a dataset not read using pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I have a csv file and tried to read it without using pandas

```
import csv
data='rainfall-last-year.csv'
temporal=''
amt=''
with open(data,'r') as this_file:
  this_file=csv.reader(this_file)
  header=next(this_file)
  print(header)

  for line in this_file:
    temporal=line[0]
    amt=line[1]
```

how can I visualize this data? (something like `this_file.head()`). I need to perform plotting operations on it too.

Upon typing `this_file` in the console, the following output is given:

```
`<_csv.reader at 0x7f61b2786e48>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used example: https://gist.github.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7#file-iris-csv

You can simple read top 10 lines by using index numbers and splicing:

Partial code:

```
f=open(data).readlines()
for i in f[:10]: # Number of line to read
    print (i.rstrip())
```

Full code:

```
import csv
data='iris.csv'
temporal=''
amt=''

f=open(data).readlines()
for i in f[:10]: # Number of line to read
    print (i.rstrip())

with open(data,'r') as this_file:
  this_file=csv.reader(this_file)
  header=next(this_file)
  print(header)

  for line in this_file:
    temporal=line[0]
    amt=line[1]
```

Output:

```
sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,setosa
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,setosa
['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'species']
```

Update:

```
import csv
data='rainfall-last-year.csv'
temporal=''
amt=''

f=open(data).readlines()[1:]
mmvals=[]
for i in f[:10]:
    vals=i.rstrip()
    mmvals.append(float(vals.split(",")[1]))
print (min(mmvals),max(mmvals))
```

Output:

```
0.0 8.4
```

Comment: This certainly helps me but could you please take a look at the data at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Wg35VQnSBGohKTG2uOXOXZetyugIkeN/view?usp=sharing   When I use your code for this data, everything is converted to strings for some reason. I need to find the min and max of the respective columns

Comment: I'm still struggling with the values in the 0th column. I cant seem to transform it to int or datetime format for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes sure. I can help. Please accept this as an answer, since your original question was answered and open another question.

Comment: Sure. could you please refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348449/how-to-convert-string-data-to-suitable-data-types